# FileCopy gives Error 53 File Not Found

Tags: vba, excel

**The Problem:**

As stated above, I have a line of code, `FileCopy String5, String6`, that is giving Error 53: File Not Found. I have determined that the error is occurring with String6. I need another pair of eyes to help me find the error.

**What I've Tried:**

- Printing String6 to a cell to make sure it is correct
- Copying String6 into Windows Explorer and Windows-->Run (after deleting the file name, it hasn't been created yet due to the macro error) to make sure they open the folder correctly
- Used Dir function to double check that Excel can see the copyto directory after I've made it
- Because the files about to be copied come from a folder that was unzipped prior to the code, adding a 1 second wait in case the new files somehow hadn't been detected (basically trying everything now)

I'm open to any suggestions. Here's an **updated** section of my code in case it helps, and I'd be happy to post the whole thing as well:

```
'File Manipulation
'Find a file in StrDir1 with String2 extension, "*.dat"
String4 = Dir(StrDir1 & String2)
Do While String4 <> ""
    'Save the complete path of the file found
    String5 = StrDir1 & String4
    For Loop1 = LBound(Array1) To UBound(Array1)
        'Array1 has file identifiers in it that identify who the file belongs to for later separation and folder placement
        If InStr(String5, Array1(Loop1)) Then
            'We found a file with the identifier, save the future complete path of the copied file
            String6 = StrDir1 & Array2(Loop1) & String4
            'Create the containing folder where the file will be copied if it does not already exist
            String10 = vbNullString
            On Error Resume Next
            'Check if the folder already exists
            String10 = Dir(StrDir1 & Array2(Loop1), vbDirectory)
            On Error GoTo 0
            'If it doesn't exist, create it
            If String10 = vbNullString Then
                MkDir StrDir1 & Array2(Loop1)
            End If
            'String8 is the file type, it was determined earlier
            If String8 = "997" Then
                String7 = "\\(directory)\" & String4
                'This works, which makes me think the problem is String6.
                Object2.CopyFile String5, String7
                'For testing purposes
                ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(1, 1).Value = String5
                ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(2, 1).Value = String6
                String10 = Dir(StrDir1 & Array2(Loop1), vbDirectory)
                'Back to the real code
                'When these lines are commented, Error 53, file not found. When uncommented, Error 76, path not found.
'                String5 = " & String5 & "
'                String6 = " & String6 & "
                'Error occurs here
                Object2.CopyFile String5, String6
                Kill String5
                String4 = Dir(StrDir1 & String2)
                'code continues
```

To reiterate, the error occurs on the `Object2.CopyFile String5, String6` line of the above code.

Here are String5 and String6 at the time of error, in case it helps anyone. These values are copied from Cells 1,1 and 2,1:

String5: \\extremely long directory\extremely long file name.ext

String6: \\extremely long directory\extremely long file name.ext

**Update:** I switched to fso.copyfile and I also tried adding quotes around my strings to avoid any problems with the directories containing spaces. When I added quotes, the error changed to Error 76, path not found. Does this help troubleshoot my code?

(I also added a few more lines to my code snippet to hopefully demonstrate this isn't a Dir() problem to the best of my knowledge, but since I am new to Dir(), Tim could still be right.)

**Update 2:** I think String6 is too long. I'm using the following code to test but Excel keeps crashing after successfully copying the file when I try to run it. Is there something I need to know about FSO to prevent that?

```
Sub M2Pathtester()

Dim String5 As String
Dim String6 As String
Dim Object2 As Object

Set Object2 = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")

String5 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(1, 1)
String6 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(2, 1)
Object2.CopyFile String5, String6

End Sub
```

**Final Update:**
Yes, the string was too long. Excel still repeatedly crashes (after successfully copying) using the fso.copyfile method, but when I reverted back to FileCopy, it worked smoothly.

Comment: I am not sure what SO formatting method I am not using correctly but when I go to edit my comment, there are two backslashes, they just don't show on the post.

Comment: It looks like you're nesting calls to `Dir()` - that method is "global", so you cannot use nested calls: once you call it with a parameter in the inner loop, then the outer loop is also reset.  An alternative approach is to first collect all the "outer loop" paths in an array or collection: then you can loop over that and use your "inner" loop safely.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer Tim. I don't know enough about `Dir()` yet to understand how overwriting a loop that checks whether there's more work to do would affect a command inside the loop when it has already been determined for that iteration that there is more work to be done. However, I trust your experience and knowledge. Once I get more confirmation and change things according to your suggestion, I'll comment again asking you to post as an answer if everything works. Thanks again!

Comment: Tim, I also realized last night that this loop is not a loop as it is typically defined. Because the file that serves as the loop's iteration point is deleted each time, at the bottom of the iteration there is a copy of the line before the loop starts, `String4 = Dir(StrDir1 & String2)`. It repeats until the folder is empty. The loop mostly serves to repeat the same commands over and over again, but it does not act on every member of a set while leaving the set intact as usual.

Comment: I was going on the first two lines of your code, where it looks like your setting up a Do Whlie loop using Dir(), and then that you call Dir() again within that loop.  If you added the full code then that would be helpful - I was taking clues from the indentation of what you posted.

Comment: I might do that but I think I just figured it out. I was thinking that since the String6 directory is created earlier in the code, that it could be a timing issue somehow. I made the String6 directory by hand and made a new macro where the only commands are setting up the strings and filesystemobjects and copying. It didn't work, but when I made a new directory with a shorter name it did copy successfully before Excel crashed. Trying again to see if it works without crashing, but I think the problem is String6 is too long.

Thanks for taking clues, sorry you didn't have the full code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was that String6 exceeded the maximum character length. So be warned that that is a possibility when getting Error 53 or Error 76 when using FileCopy or fso.copyfile.

Note: Because of my inexperience with FSO, this might not be exactly/technically correct, but I hope it informs you enough to get you on the right path if you're stuck.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any obvious reason that you should be getting an error 53 for the destination file.  Some sources indicate that FileCopy can be quirky with spaces in the path, but that really should be giving an error 52 if that's the case.  I found one other report of somebody claiming that they needed to stop hiding know file extensions in the destination folder to avoid an error with FileCopy, but I'm not sure I'm buying that one.

I'd make sure that you have the appropriate permissions in the folder you're writing to, and use the Scripting.FilesystemObject to perform the copy instead - it's typically more robust:

```
Dim fso As Object
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

fso.CopyFile String5, String6
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I am completely self-taught from mrexcel and stackexchange for vba and this project has been my introduction to manipulating files outside of Excel. Both your research and your advice about FSO will benefit me a lot!